# Тире или двоеточие перед перечнем?

Tags: пунктуация

Если приводится перечень, записанный в строку, какой знак препинания выбрать? Как написать правильно: *Статьи, опубликованные мной: статья 1, статья 2, статья 3* или *Статьи, опубликованные мной, — статья 1, статья 2, статья 3*?

Answer (score 3):

Перечень - это перечисление. Перед перечислением ставится двоеточие.

Answer (score 2):

И то и другое верно, но если их много, лучше всё-таки двоеточие как оформление предложения с однородными членами и обобщающим словом.

Но я бы написала: *Мной опубликованы следующие статьи: статья 1, статья 2, статья 3*.  Или: *Имеются следующие публикации:....*

Для научного стиля больше подходит последнее предложение.